# Find the condition when the area of a varying triangle is minimum

Tags: geometry

When I use Geogebra to play with the problem [$R$ is the midpoint of $MN$ and the points where $AC$ intersects $MD$ and $ND$ are $P$ and $Q$, respectively. Show that $PR=QR$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1418282/r-is-the-midpoint-of-mn-and-the-points-where-ac-intersects-md-and-nd-a) , I have the following interesting findings:-

[image]

If I let M be a movable point (along AB), then $\triangle PRQ$ will remain as an isosceles right-angled triangle with PR // DC and RQ // AD all the time. The proof of this fact is not difficult and a partial solution can be found in my proof to the same post.

It is not difficult to see the $[⊿PQR]_{max}$ occurs when M, P, and A coincide and R becomes the midpoint of AB. How about $[⊿PQR]_{min}$? My guess is when AP = QC.

Comment: If I saw correctly, you have $PR=RQ=\frac{1+x_0^2}{2+2x_0}$ and that $PR\perp RQ$. So you have to minimize $PR\cdot RQ/2=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1+x_0^2}{2+2x_0})^2$

Comment: I think you mean $RQ$//$AD$.

Comment: @G-man Fixed. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The area of $PQR$ is proportional to $PQ^2$, so that one must find when $PQ$ is minimum. But $PQ$ is just that part of line $AC$ lying inside $\angle MDN$, which is of fixed amplitude: the minimum occurs when the bisector of $\angle MDN$ is perpendicular to $AC$, that is when $AP=QC$.

This last statement should be quite obvious, anyway here's a simple proof. If $H$ is the midpoint of $AC$, let $\angle PDQ=2\gamma$, $\angle PDH=\gamma+\delta$ and $\angle QDH=\gamma-\delta$. We have then
$$
PQ=DH[\tan(\gamma+\delta)+\tan(\gamma-\delta)]=
2DH\tan\gamma{1+\tan^2\delta\over1-\tan^2\gamma\tan^2\delta}
$$
and this is obviously minimum for $\delta=0$.

Comment: At that instant, the bisector of $∠MDN$ is just BD. BD is now the axis of symmetry of the whole picture. Tx for providing a proof to my guess.